# Android download from Azure blob storage results in invalid file

Tags: android, azure, blob

From my Android app I try to download from the windows Azure blob storage using the following URL: http://iclyps.blob.core.windows.net/broadcasts/23_6.mp4

The resulting file is corrupt when I download it from within my app. Same error occurs when I download it using the default Browser or Chrome. Also from the Easy Downloader app, the same error occurs. Only a download from my PC or using Firefox Beta from the Android device (or emulator), the file is retrieved correctly.

I use the following code (snippet):

```
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), BUFSIZE);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                context.openFileOutput(TMPFILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), BUFSIZE);
        /*
         * Read bytes to the buffer in chunks of BUFSIZE bytes until there is nothing more to read.
         * Each chunk is written to the output file.
         */
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        int nBytes = 0;
        int tBytes = 0;
        while ((nBytes = bis.read(buf, 0, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, nBytes);
            tBytes += nBytes;
        }
        if (tBytes == 0) throw new Exception("no bytes received");
        bos.flush();
        MobyLog.d(TAG, "download succeeded: #bytes = " + Integer.toString(tBytes));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MobyLog.e(TAG, "download failed: " + e);
        context.deleteFile(TMPFILE);    // remove possibly present partial file.
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (bis != null) try { bis.close(); } catch (IOException e) {MobyLog.e(TAG, "bis close exception: " + e); };
        if (bos != null) try { bos.close(); } catch (IOException e) {MobyLog.e(TAG, "bos close exception: " + e); };
    }
```

Analyzing the files shows that the first part (about 700K) of the original file is repeated a number of times in the corrupted files, resulting in an invalid mp4 file.

Putting the file on another webserver (Apache/IIS), and downloading the file from that location does result in a correct download.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem performing a download from Azure? Can someone provide a solution?

Cheers,
Harald...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java) in your android app?

Our scenario is slightly different in that we using the sdk to pull and push images from blob storage to a custom android app. But the fundamentals should be the same.

Comment: might want to check the meta-data type on the file as well. I've seen that sometimes cause problems.

Comment: I thought about the Azure SDK, but the files are not located on Azure storage all the time; pretty hard to distinguish between those situations.

Comment: Content-Type tag of the file is in all cases video/mp4.